# can not access local rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I build up a rails app in mac OS and try to use other device (in same private lan) to connect to this local service. However my device can not access to this url => "http://192.168.1.107:3000"

My console is below:

```
chris$ rails server --binding=192.168.1.107
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://192.168.1.107:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

It works fine in local machine both "http://localhost:3000" and "http://192.168.1.107:3000" but other device still can not access "http://192.168.1.107:3000"

Any suggestion for that? thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to bind to an internal ip ? - edit ah I see, to access it from mobile

Comment: just for testing. I try both on "rails s" and "rails server --binding=192.168.1.107" but same results.

Comment: You don't need to bind to the local IP to access from another device. Leave it at `localhost:3000` and use the servers IP and 3000 to access from another device. From what mobile you are testing? Android allows forwarding while debugging allowing you to access `localhost:3000` in your device.

Comment: If you want to access your localhost from public network try https://github.com/ssilab/localtunnel gem!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

If firewall blocks 3000 try this:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

Now access [your-computer-ip]:80

You could also use a service like https://localtunnel.me/ (if you are not on the same local domain)